# Java Beginner: Ignoring While loop

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Hellno {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
            findBiggest(s);
            System.out.println(findBiggest(s));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can't find that file");
        }
    }

    public static String findBiggest(Scanner scan) {
        int count0 = 0;
        int count1 = 0;
        String srs = "";

        while (scan.hasNext()) { //how do i make this the longest?
            String nsrs = scan.next();
            count0 = nsrs.length();

            if (count0 > count1) { // if the new length is bigger than what was solidified
                count1 = count0; //new solidification of number
                count0 = 0; // count becomes 0  to start again
                srs = nsrs; // nsrs has been solidified as the new biggest String
            }

            else if (count0 <= count1) { // if the new length is smaller than what was solidified
                count0 = 0; //then we start again with dummyCount = 0;
             }   
        }
        return srs;}}
```

I am trying to read from a text file, find out what is the longest string and return that string. However, this coding ignores all of while() and seems to jump to return srs. Why??

Comment: Make sure that the file is in the correct location, it has data within it and then try to set a breakpoint on the while block and step through

Comment: Both text file & java file are on my desktop. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It must be because it is not reading anything ... Print it to screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `findBiggest` twice on the same `Scanner`.  The first call presumably finds the biggest word and returns it, but it's ignored.  The second call finds no words, and the `while` loop has no iterations.

Just call `findBiggest` once.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
System.out.println(findBiggest(s));
```

Answer (score 0):

need to set a delimiter on the scanner

```
  Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```